# Working with application in Java using maps

Tags: javafx, maps

I have trouble with my Java application. I'm writing a program that connects to public transport API and perform some operations, which includes showing map of Warsaw with bus stops. I want to add an EventHandler function that allows to tap on a bus stop on the map, which will result in showing a box with some informations about this bus stop. How can I do such a thing?
My application so far:
Main.java:

```
package gui;

import api.Api;
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.ServiceFactory;
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.Services;
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.StorageService;
import com.gluonhq.maps.MapPoint;
import com.gluonhq.maps.MapView;
import com.gluonhq.maps.demo.PoiLayer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends Application{
    private ContentType currentContent = ContentType.SCHEDULE;
    private HashMap<ContentType, Pane> contentPaneMap;
    private HBox buttonBox;
    private Stage stage;
    private Theme theme;
    private final int height = 500;
    private final int width = 800;
    private final ToggleGroup menuButtonToggle = new ToggleGroup();
    private String selectedStopId;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.stage = primaryStage;
        theme = Theme.DARK;
        buttonBox = new HBox();
        buttonBox.getChildren().addAll(getMenuButtons());
        initContentPanes();
        getContentPaneAndResetStage();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void getContentPaneAndResetStage(){
        Pane contentPane = contentPaneMap.get(currentContent);
        VBox rootPane = new VBox();
        rootPane.getChildren().addAll(buttonBox, contentPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, width, height);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(theme.cssFile);
        stage.setScene(scene);
    }

    private List<ToggleButton> getMenuButtons(){
        List<ToggleButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ContentType contentType:ContentType.values()){
            ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton(contentType.buttonText);
            button.setPrefWidth((double) width/4);
            button.setOnAction(e -> {
                Main.this.currentContent = contentType;
                getContentPaneAndResetStage();
            });
            buttonList.add(button);
            button.setToggleGroup(Main.this.menuButtonToggle);
        }
        return buttonList;
    }

    private void initContentPanes(){
        contentPaneMap = new HashMap<>();
        Api.saveLocalisationToCache();
        contentPaneMap.put(ContentType.MAP, getMapPane());
        contentPaneMap.put(ContentType.SCHEDULE, getSchedulePane());
        contentPaneMap.put(ContentType.ROUTE, getRoutePane());
        contentPaneMap.put(ContentType.SETTINGS, getSettingsPane());
    }

    private Pane getSchedulePane(){
        VBox schedulePane = new VBox();
        Label stopNameLabel = new Label("Nazwa przystanku: ");
        stopNameLabel.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        TextField stopName = new TextField();
        stopName.setOnAction(e -> {
            List<String> stopId = Api.getId(stopName.getText());
            selectedStopId = null;
            schedulePane.getChildren().remove(1);
            schedulePane.getChildren().add(getContentForSchedulePane(stopId, stopName.getText()));
        });
        schedulePane.getChildren().add(new HBox(stopNameLabel, stopName));
        if (selectedStopId == null) schedulePane.getChildren().add(new Pane(new Label("Nie znaleziono przystanku")));
        else schedulePane.getChildren().add(new Label(selectedStopId));
        return schedulePane;
    }

    private Pane getContentForSchedulePane(List<String> stopId, String stopName){
        if (stopId.size() == 0) return new Pane(new Label("Nie znaleziono przystanku"));
        if (stopId.size() == 1) {
            String stop1id = stopId.get(0);
            Label stopNameLabel = new Label("Przystanek " + stopName.toUpperCase() + " (id " + stop1id + ")");
            stopNameLabel.setPadding(new Insets(5));
            VBox newContentPane = new VBox(stopNameLabel);
            ChoiceBox<String> busStopNr = new ChoiceBox<>(
                    FXCollections.observableArrayList(List.of(new String[]{"01", "02"})));
            busStopNr.setValue("01");
            ChoiceBox<String> lineChoice = new ChoiceBox<>(
                    FXCollections.observableArrayList(Api.getLines(stop1id, busStopNr.getValue())));
            Label times = new Label();
            lineChoice.setOnAction(
                    e -> times.setText(Api.getTimes(stop1id, busStopNr.getValue(), lineChoice.getValue()).toString()));
            busStopNr.setOnAction(
                    e -> lineChoice.setItems(
                            FXCollections.observableArrayList(Api.getLines(stop1id, busStopNr.getValue()))));
            newContentPane.getChildren().addAll(
                    new HBox(new Label("Nr słupka: "), busStopNr),
                    new HBox(new Label("Nr linii: "), lineChoice),
                    times);
            return newContentPane;
        }
        GridPane newButtonPane = new GridPane();
        int i = 1; int j = 0;
        for (String id:stopId) {
            Button b = new Button(id);
            b.setOnAction(event -> {
                selectedStopId = b.getText();
                contentPaneMap.get(ContentType.SCHEDULE).getChildren().remove(1);
                contentPaneMap.get(ContentType.SCHEDULE).getChildren()
                        .add(getContentForSchedulePane(Collections.singletonList(b.getText()), stopName));
            });
            ((GridPane) newButtonPane).add(b, i, j);
            i = (i+1)%4+1; j = i==1?j+1:j;
        }
        return newButtonPane;
    }

    private Pane getRoutePane(){return new VBox(new Circle(20, Color.BLUE));}

    private Pane getMapPane(){
        MapView mapView = new MapView();
        PoiLayer poiLayer = new PoiLayer();
        List<Map<String, String>> pointList = Api.getLocalization();
        for (Map<String, String> stop: pointList){
            MapPoint point = new MapPoint(Double.parseDouble(stop.get("szer_geo")), Double.parseDouble(stop.get("dlug_geo")));
            poiLayer.addPoint(point, new Circle(3, Color.RED));
        }
        mapView.setCenter(new MapPoint(52.230926, 21.006701));
        mapView.setZoom(13);
        mapView.addLayer(poiLayer);
        return new StackPane(mapView);
    }

    public void getInfo(){

    }
    private Pane getSettingsPane(){
        GridPane settingsPane = new GridPane();
        ChoiceBox<Theme> themeChoiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Theme.values()));
        themeChoiceBox.setOnAction(e -> {
            Main.this.theme = themeChoiceBox.getValue();
            getContentPaneAndResetStage();
        });
        Label themeLabel = new Label("Motyw: ");
        themeLabel.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        settingsPane.add(themeLabel, 1, 1);
        settingsPane.add(themeChoiceBox, 2, 1);
        settingsPane.setHgap(10);
        settingsPane.setVgap(10);
        settingsPane.setGridLinesVisible(false);
        return settingsPane;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.setProperty("javafx.platform", "Desktop");
        System.setProperty("http.agent", "Gluon Mobile/1.0.1");
        StorageService storageService = new StorageService() {
            @Override
            public Optional<File> getPrivateStorage() {
                return Optional.of(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            }
            @Override
            public Optional<File> getPublicStorage(String s) {
                return getPrivateStorage();
            }
            @Override
            public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
                return getPrivateStorage().isPresent() && getPrivateStorage().get().canWrite();
            }
            @Override
            public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
                return getPrivateStorage().isPresent() && getPrivateStorage().get().canRead();
            }
        };
        ServiceFactory<StorageService> storageServiceServiceFactory = new ServiceFactory<>() {
            @Override
            public Class<StorageService> getServiceType() {
                return StorageService.class;
            }

            @Override
            public Optional<StorageService> getInstance() {
                return Optional.of(storageService);
            }
        };
        Services.registerServiceFactory(storageServiceServiceFactory);
    }
}
```

api.java:

```
package api;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Api {

    private static final String baseUrl = "https://api.um.warszawa.pl/api/action/";
    private static final String apikey = "95904037-5fdc-48d5-bd7f-c9f8d0b28947";
    private static final String pathToLocalisationCache = "./.cache/stop-localisation.json";

    private static HttpURLConnection getConnection(String urlString){
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            assert url != null;
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
    //Współrzędne przystanków
    public static List<Map<String,String>> getLocalization() {
        File cacheFile = new File(pathToLocalisationCache);
        String data;
        if(!cacheFile.exists()){
            String url = baseUrl+"dbstore_get?id=ab75c33d-3a26-4342-b36a-6e5fef0a3ac3&apikey="+apikey;
            HttpURLConnection connection = Api.setParameters(getConnection(url));
            data = Api.readData(connection);
        } else{
            data = readLocalisationFromCache();
        }

        List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        assert data != null;
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("result");
        for(int j=0; j<arr.length();j++){
            JSONObject obj1 = arr.getJSONObject(j);
            JSONArray arr1 = obj1.getJSONArray("values");
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length();i++){
                String value = arr1.getJSONObject(i).getString("value");
                String key = arr1.getJSONObject(i).getString("key");
                map.put(key, value);
            }
            list.add(map);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void saveLocalisationToCache(){
        File file = new File(pathToLocalisationCache);
        if (file.exists()) return;
        try{
            boolean fileCreated = true;
            if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) fileCreated = file.getParentFile().mkdir();
            if (!fileCreated) throw new IOException("Unable to create cache directory");
            fileCreated = file.createNewFile();
            if (!fileCreated) throw new IOException("Unable to create file");
            String url = baseUrl+"dbstore_get?id=ab75c33d-3a26-4342-b36a-6e5fef0a3ac3&apikey="+apikey;
            HttpURLConnection connection = setParameters(getConnection(url));
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder());
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder());
            in.transferTo(out);
            in.close(); out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String readLocalisationFromCache(){
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToLocalisationCache));
            StringBuilder dataSB = new StringBuilder();
            reader.lines().forEach(dataSB::append);
            reader.close();
            return dataSB.toString();
        } catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        return null;
    }


    //id przystanku po nazwie
    public static List<String> getId(String n) {
        StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            String[] testStrings = {n};
            for (String s : testStrings) {
                String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                name.append(encodedString);
            }
        } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        String url = baseUrl+"dbtimetable_get?id=b27f4c17-5c50-4a5b-89dd-236b282bc499&name="+name+"&apikey="+apikey;

        HttpURLConnection connection = Api.setParameters(getConnection(url));
        String data = Api.readData(connection);
        assert data != null;
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
        Pattern integerPattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = integerPattern.matcher(json.toString());
        List<String> linesList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            linesList.add(matcher.group());
        }
        return linesList;
    }

    // Zwraca liste linii dla konkretnego przystanku i nr slupka
    public static List<String> getLines(String idPrzystanku, String nrSlupka) {
        String url = baseUrl+"dbtimetable_get?id=88cd555f-6f31-43ca-9de4-66c479ad5942&busstopId="+
                idPrzystanku+"&busstopNr="+nrSlupka+"&apikey="+apikey;

        HttpURLConnection connection = Api.setParameters(getConnection(url));
        String data = Api.readData(connection);
        assert data != null;
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
        Pattern integerPattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = integerPattern.matcher(json.toString());
        List<String> linesList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            linesList.add(matcher.group());
        }
        return linesList;
    }

    //Zwraca listę czas dla danego przystanku i linii
    public static List<String> getTimes(String idPrzystanku, String nrSlupka, String line) {
        String url = baseUrl+"dbtimetable_get?id=e923fa0e-d96c-43f9-ae6e-60518c9f3238&busstopId="+
                idPrzystanku+"&busstopNr="+nrSlupka+"&line="+line+"&apikey="+apikey;

        HttpURLConnection connection = Api.setParameters(getConnection(url));
        String data = Api.readData(connection);

        List<String> times = new ArrayList<>();
        assert data != null;
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("result");
        for(int j=0; j<arr.length();j++){
            JSONObject obj1 = arr.getJSONObject(j);
            JSONArray arr1 = obj1.getJSONArray("values");
            JSONObject obj2 = arr1.getJSONObject(5);
            times.add(obj2.getString("value"));
        }
        return times;
    }

    //Odczytuje dane
    public static String readData(HttpURLConnection connection) {
        InputStream inStream;
        try {
            inStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            sb.append(in.next());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    //Ustala parametry połączenia
    public static HttpURLConnection setParameters(HttpURLConnection
                                                          connection) {
        try {
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token " + apikey);
        try {
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                System.out.println("Response code: "
                        + connection.getResponseCode() + " " + connection.getResponseMessage());
                Platform.exit(); // ze względu na javafx
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to do it and I will be very grateful if someone will help me.

Comment: [mcve] please (mind the __M__!)

Comment: Is there a reason for all the `Swing` and `awt` imports? Do not use those unless you have a very good reason. I could not see a reason when I skimmed through your code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my work experience on map libraries with JavaFX, I can share an approach you can take here. You can simply add a Mouse click event handler on the `MapView` and in that event you can catch the coordinates/`Point` where the user clicks on the screen. Then you can compare that point clicked by the user with one of the location Map points you want your user to click and see if it matches (by checking a distance between the user click position and the map coordinate of the bus stop). I have applied this approach in a different map library but similar can be applied here with some tweaks and adjustments.

```
List<Map<String, String>> pointList = Api.getLocalization();

        mapView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

                Point2D clickedMapCoordinates = mapView.screenToLocal(new Point2D(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY()));

                for (Map<String, String> stop: pointList){
                    MapPoint stopPoint = new MapPoint(Double.parseDouble(stop.get("szer_geo")), Double.parseDouble(stop.get("dlug_geo")));

                    Point2D mapStopPoint = new Point2D(stopPoint.getLongitude(), stopPoint.getLatitude());

                    // if user clicked on map near the position(lat,lng) of a stop
                    // then trigger the logic, you can change the distance threshold value according to your need
                    if(mapStopPoint.distance(clickedMapCoordinates) < 0.0001)
                    {
                        // perform your logic here about the stop point point...
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Another approach which I suppose you can take is put a click event handler on the `Circle` object for the bus stop point and then check if the user's clicked circle matches the coordinates of a bus stop point.

```
Circle circle = new Circle(3, Color.RED);
        circle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if(mouseEvent.getSource() instanceof Circle)
                {
                    Circle clickedCircle = (Circle) mouseEvent.getSource();
                    Point2D clickedPoint = mapView.screenToLocal(clickedCircle.getCenterX(), clickedCircle.getCenterY())

                    for (Map<String, String> stop: pointList){
                        MapPoint point = new MapPoint(Double.parseDouble(stop.get("szer_geo")), Double.parseDouble(stop.get("dlug_geo")));

                        if(clickedPoint.getX() == point.getLongitude() && clickedPoint.getY() == point.getLatitude())
                        {
                            // this is the clicked map point (bus stop point)
                            // perform your logic here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

If the second approach doesn't work, try debugging and checking the clicked point and bus stop point coordinates values and adjust them. Hope this helps you in some way.